# TypeError: Can not read property of undefined(reading 'then') Angular unit test case

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Here is my method in ts file and test case, When I am trying to run my test case, I am getting undefined error reading then.

```
onCancel(){
    this.router.navigate(['hello']).then(() =>{
    window.router.reload();
    });
    }
```

test-case spec.ts -

```
    it("should navigate to hello", function () 
    {
    component.onCancel();
    expect(routerSpy.navigate).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
```

Comment: Well, `this.router.navigate` is returning undefined. Looks like you might have a spy on it. Does your spy return a promise or an object with a `then` function?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. No, its not returning anything.. this is the method -onCancel(){
    this.router.navigate(['hello']).then(() =>{
    window.router.reload();
    });
    }

Comment: @HereticMonkey Its a promise returning void.